# Ad Control in Windows Phone 7?

Tags: silverlight, windows-phone-7, windows-phone, ads, advertisement-server

I am developing a Windows Phone7 App. In my app I need to show an advertisement. I am planning to use Microsoft's Ad Control for this.

Is it possible to show my own advertisements in the Ad Control. ?..

Is it possible to use OpenX ads in Ad Control ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Microsoft Ad Control will only display Microsoft Ads, if you want to show your own Ads I would recommend something like the WP7 Unified Ad control, available from Codeplex (http://wpunifiedad.codeplex.com/)

The control allows you to specify which Ad providers are displayed, and the percentage chance that they are chosen.  I don't believe that it currently supports OpenX Ads, but you can always raise that in the discussions on CodePlex.

I am using the control on the WP7 Apps that I have written (PayPhone Lite, LatinIslands Free and Bridges Free) and it works well.

HTH - Rupert.

Comment: Thanks Rupert. Which control you are using ? Microsoft AdControl or WP7 Unified Ad control ?

Comment: I am using the WP7 Unified Ad Control, which acts as a 'wrapper' for the real Ad Provider controls, giving you a single unified interface with which to interact with the other controls.

So for my Apps I am using the Microsoft Ad Control, and the AdDuplex control to serve ads.